# Purpose/Usage of Boot Segments

Tags: microcontroller

I would like to find out more about the purpose of a boot segment, the segment of program memory that is declared by the user, and I would like to ask the following questions to have a concise understanding.

1. Purpose of a boot segment?
2. What functionalists does it allow, that you cant do otherwise?
3. Can I have an example?
4. Have you seen any examples that made you think "That is a really smart/cool way of doing this!"

I would also like to thank you in advance for your time and sharing your experiences,

Kind Regards,

Comment: I've never heard of a microcontroller that had a "boot sector". Can you tell us where you got that impression? A "sector" generally refers to off-chip storage, such as a hard drive or flash drive. Microcontrollers have __vectors__ for reset and interrupts.

Comment: I apparently used the wrong word, it should have been segment. Updated Question =)

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. What is a "segment" in this context? Are you talking about a linker/loader map file?

Comment: I just found out what you mean JoeHass, Apparently uControllers dont have a boot segment but instead it is something that the user defines the BS segment with in the Program Memory. I will update the Question again. Updated :) What do you think now?

Comment: Again, we don't know what you mean by a "boot segment". That phrase has no specific meaning when talking about the design of a microcontroller. Please tell us what that phrase means to you.

Comment: A slight stab in the dark here but is this the sort of thing you mean: On a number of my embedded systems I have a small separate boot-loader in one segment of ROM and the main code stored separately in other segments.  The boot loader normally just jumps to the main code but can be used for example to enable firmware updates if required.

Comment: My apologize I assumed that word would be recognized far easier. I have added that it is a segment of program memory. I also removed the word create which I think may have given the impression of design of a uController.

Comment: @WarrenHill yes, so if you had to define that what would you call it?

Comment: Possibly a "boot-loader"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add onto Dave Tweed's answer: many flash ICs have a specifically designated boot sector. Depending on the specific device, there are different characteristics of the boot sector vs. the remaining sectors. For example:

- Some devices allow hardware write-protection of that sector separately from the rest of the device. This allows the design to absolutely forbid updating the boot loader in the field while allowing in-system update of the remaining code. This is important since if the boot loader is corrupted, the device is probably dead, while the boot loader may be able to recover from other device corruption.
- Some devices make the boot sector small than the normal sector size (with one or more small sectors to make up the space). This allows the system designer to dedicate a smaller part of the flash to the boot loader.

Since some processors power-on boot from the lowest flash address and some from the highest, you will often find two varients of flash devices, with the special boot secotr at the low or high end.

Comment: Microchip's PIC32, based on MIPS architecture, is an example of a microcontroller that has a Boot and Program Flash.  One of the advantages of a boot segment is that you can update the program area in place, by flashing new code from the boot segment.

Comment: So the whole purpose is just for the boot loader? this designated space is not used for anything else?

Comment: @VolT - If you're not booting from the device or you don't have a separate boot loader (not field reflashable), there's no reason not to use the boot sector like any other sector.

Comment: I understand @DoxyLover Thank you. Now my question has become identifying the uses of bootloaders! But ill leave that for another question =)

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm going to take a stab at an answer anyway.

When a MCU comes out of hardware reset, the peripherals are generally in a quiescent state, but internal memory and registers (except for the PC and status register) are generally uninitialized.

However — and particularly when working with a high-level (compiled) language, most of the code is generated to work in an environment in which certain registers have well-defined values, and memory has certain data structures in place, such as a stack, a heap, and initialized global/static data.

It is the job of the "boot segment" to get from the first state of affairs to the second. It is written to operate in the minimal "environment" created by the hardware reset, and it creates the more structured environment that the application code expects.

If the MCU also has access to external memory, sometimes there's a memory controller that needs to be initialized — particularly if that memory is SDRAM — and then the in-memory data structures that reside there can be initialized, too. If executable code or initialized data resides in that external memory, this must be done before those application code and data segments get loaded.

The boot segment is normally included in the "runtime library" of whatever software development system you're working with, and you rarely need to deal with it. However, it might need to be configured with application-specific parameters such as memory controller register settings and the amount of memory to be allocated to stack, heap, etc.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are describing the "startup code" (i.e., the code that runs before main()).  Or maybe the "boot loader".  But I've never heard either of these things referred to as the "boot segment".  You may be onto what the question is about but I'm skeptical that "boot segment" is the best term.